# Joomla 3x ,articles anywhere plugin ,not loading my article inside a module

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, articles, custom-module

I'm new to Joomla,so I got this problem:

I have Articles Anywhere and Modules Anywhere plugins instaled and I have a module for the Home page. In this module I try to load another module and in the second module I'm trying to load an article.

Everything loads fine except the final article wich is outputed as raw tags used to load article.I'll show you the piece of code bellow:

```
<!-- That's the home page module -->

{module module_home_article1_ro} <!-- Loading the module that contains the article -->
```

And the second module looks like this:

```
<!-- Second module -->

<article class="article-container">

   <h1 class="article-title"> {article my-article}[title]{/article}</h1>
   <div class="article-content">
       {article my-article}[text]{/article} <!-- Loading the article -->
   </div>

</article>
```

But my output to the home page is :

```
<!-- START: Modules Anywhere -->

<div class="custom">

<!-- Article -->

<article class="article-container">
   <h1 class="article-title"> {article my-article}[title]{/article}</h1>
   <div class="article-content">
       {article my-article}[text]{/article}
   </div>
</article>

<!-- End article --></div>
```

How can I stop it from outputing article tags and output the actual article ? 
Thank you for your time !

Comment: So, you have a module assigned to the home page...Inside that module you have loaded modules anywhere, which loads articles anywhere, which loads an article? I assume the outer article is a "Custom HTML" module?

Comment: Yes ,that's right,both modules are "Costum HTML"

Comment: There are definitely more effective ways of structuring your content than nested modules. I suppose you are doing this so you can have multiple types of content in the same module position?

Comment: @michael Yea,I'm doing this because I want to make it easier to make changes in a module for me and for my client. I 'm very new to Joomla so I don't know those ways, I've searched for something but I found nothing that helped me. This method just came in my mind.

Comment: I'm not sure of your particular setup, but there is an "Article" module that outputs article contents to a module position. Also, you can stack multiple modules in a single module position by setting their "position." You may try asking another question with the details of what you are trying to accomplish and the community may be able to provide the optimal setup for you and your client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the "Options" tab for **both** Custom modules, set "Prepare Content" to "Yes."

Comment: You are welcome!